# Excludе $x$ frоm this systеm оf equаtiоns.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, discriminant

How do you go about excluding $x$ from the system of equations?
\begin{cases}x^3-xy-y^3+y=0\\x^2+x-y^2=1\end{cases}

Comment: Well, I'd use a Groebner basis with a lexicographic ordering. But this is not the answer you're looking for. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried solving the quadratic equation in $x$? I don't think it's the best method, but solving for $x$ in the quadratic equation will give $x$ in terms of $y$, which can then be substituted in the cubic equation in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resultant of the two polynomials $x^3 - xy - y^3 + y$ and $x^2 + x - y^2 - 1$ with respect to $x$ is $5\,{y}^{5}-7\,{y}^{4}+6\,{y}^{3}-2\,{y}^{2}-y-1$.  That is, the equation with $x$ removed is
$5\,{y}^{5}-7\,{y}^{4}+6\,{y}^{3}-2\,{y}^{2}-y-1=0$.

Comment: Which renders $y=1$ as a solution ... .

Comment: And indeed the only real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2+x+1/4=(x+1/2)^2$. Use that and your second equation to express $x$ as a function of $y$.